# android ios any unique key for any BLE (We are working with all BLE - no manufacturer dependency) to identify it

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I am trying to find a way for How to get BLE mac in iOS???

This will be for all the BLE no manufacturer dependency will be there. We are finding a solution for the scan time.  Can I differentiate between the BLEs in scan time?

If failed to get the MAC. then is there any common thing that is useful to identify BLE cross-platform i.e android ios and web.

Thanks in advance.

I tried using UUID in iOS it's always different for the different devices for the same BLE. android is giving MAC which is unique but iOS is not capable enough to get MAC.

I am finding the common for all BLE what is the unique and common thing that all BLE posses mostly the Beacons.

Comment: You need your peripheral to expose some identifier via a GATT characteristic, otherwise there is no way to identify a specific peripheral across different iOS devices

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually want the same. Can you please let me know how can I set this GATT characteristic for BLE device that I am having.

Comment: I can't provide a specific answer as that depends on the device you are using; essentially you need to modify the firmware of your peripheral device so that it has an identifier exposed by a characteristic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Bluetooth LE advertisements contain a 6 byte MAC address which is generally useful in uniquely identifying the originating hardware device.  As you have seen, **iOS CoreBluetooth blocks the ability to read the MAC** instead substituting a 16 byte UUID as the identifier.  This identifier, however, rotates periodically, so it cannot be used to uniquely identify devices.  It is possible that over time two different identifiers will cone from the same device.

**This is a privacy restriction on iOS and there is no public API to get around it.** Two imperfect  alternatives:

- For iBeacon devices use the combination of ProximityUUID/major/minor.  (Or even the full manufacturer advertisement.) This still may not be unique in some cases as multiple beacons can advertise the same identufier.
- For other GATT devices you control, make them expose a characteristic which returns the actual MAC value.

But none of these solutions work for all BLE devices in all cases.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me in a way that I become clear now that I can't scan any BLE with a unique id. Can I scan to check whether MACAddress I have is near to me or not, using core Bluetooth iOS?

Comment: You cannot use MAC address to find any to find beacons with iOS.  Apple blocks it.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend